# Как отобразить несколько ссылок в одной строке?

Tags: теги, html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как задать несколько ссылок, что бы они отображались в одной строке. Я набираю такой код <p> <a href="">1</a> <a href="">2</a> 3</p> и получаю три строки.

Comment: Дык они у тебя итак в одной строке отображаться будут.

Comment: Да, должны в одной,  а получаю три

Comment: а в css что-то вроде - p a { display:block; } не прописано? мало ли)

Comment: 2 @Palmervan ну в условии нет файла css.

какой вопрос такой ответ.

Comment: > Скорее всего, ошибка где-то в css.
> Либо a{display:block}, либо
> p{width:1px} Полюбому, для более конкретного ответа покажите CSS относящиеся к этим элементам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, ошибка где-то в css. Либо `a{display:block}`, либо `p{width:1px}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
p{
 white-space:nowrap;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

да, ошибка в css, в чистом html коде у тебя указанно все правильно.